# Mac terminal not valid context

Tags: java, macos, terminal, virtual-machine

I'm a new Mac user. I'm receiving this error every time I open my terminal and I'm not sure what its about. I was hoping someone can help me with this issue. Thanks in advance

```
**Error**

/Users/myfolder/.zshenv:export:1: not valid in this context:     /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-14.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Comment: Just guessing here, but are you using sdkman? That generates a line in the .zshrc saying `"#THIS MUST BE AT THE END OF THE FILE FOR SDKMAN TO WORK!!!"` - maybe you appended stuff that should not be there?

Comment: @thinkgruen I have no clue what I did. How do I undo everything? Like can I start over or something?

Comment: you could just `open .zshrc` (or use an editor of your choice) and move everything else further up. the last two lines in mine contain `export SDKMAN_DIR...` and `[[ -s ... ]] && source ... `

Comment: Ok. How do I open .Zshrc?

Comment: You can type the `open .zshrc` command in the terminal and an editor should open.

Comment: its saying that the file docent exist

Comment: What is the content of `open .zshenv`?